# HomeAsUp icon showing a bit off

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have this weird issue with the `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` because it is showing the left arrow a bit off the layout.

This is how the left icon looks

[image: left arrow]

This is the code I use to set the `Toolbar` as the `SupportActionBar`

```
Toolbar toolbar;
...
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And this is the activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dip"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ml.dannyb.packagetracker.workers.SquareImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvPackageDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabEditPackage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_white_24dp"
        app:elevation="10dip"
        app:layout_behavior="ml.dannyb.packagetracker.workers.ScrollAwareFABBehavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Why it shows time in the middle of status bar and why battery icon is different?

Comment: It's Cyanogenmod 12.1.. There are a few options to change your StatusBar in it that are really nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem seems to be Android 5.0+ specific.. I get the indicator placed correctly on other pre 5.0 Android versions and I fixed it by adding a styles-v21/styles.xml file where I extended the base theme.. That was all I needed to do so if anyone else gets this problem now you have the fix! :)

Answer (score 0):

See:
https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-keylines-spacing

Set:
`Status bar` height: `24dp`
`Toolbar` height: `56dp`

Remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

Comment: But how do I set StatusBar height?

Comment: just remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

Comment: I did that but no chance